# How to implement an AsyncTask pattern to avoid too verbose code

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm implementing an app that uses many methods that requires an `AsyncTask` with a waiting dialog.
Actually my approach is to use every time an inner class that extends AsyncTask

something like

```
 private class AsyncOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CurrencyConverterActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Waiting...");
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           ...
          return null
         }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void params){
            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //dialogs according status the                     
                    //int status is a static variable declared in external class
                }

            });


        }
```

since with this approach i have to write this inner class too many times and this result in dirty code not well readable, I'm looking for a smarter solution

Could someone help me?

Comment: are you using code from androidhive? it sucks(lots of bad code practies) ... you don't need to call runOnUiThread from onPostExecute ... you can also get rid of dialogs inside AsyncTask(i think that using dialogs atevery asynctask it is bad UI pattern)... just use some indeterminate progress bar in your view

Comment: We need more info on what each AsyncTask needs in order to work. All just int,string, etc.. or custom objects?

Comment: @selvin I don't know this site. I use the dialog in case something goes wrong or to alert the user about something. However the code is only a generic sample to give a general idea.

Comment: @mario
in my app there are at least 200 methods that requires async task for this reason I need  generic approach to use for every method invocation without rewrite same code too many times.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the same network each time you use the async task?
If yes, then you can have one class which extends the async and pass the values for each call. You can have response listener to get the response from the method called the async

Something like this:

```
MainActivity:
First method:
AsyncOperation asyncCall = new AsyncOperation(MainActivity.this, "abc", "bcd");
asyncCall.execute();

Second method:
AsyncOperation asyncCall = new AsyncOperation(MainActivity.this, "aaa", "bbb");
asyncCall.execute();

callback(…){

}


Async Class:
 private class AsyncOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

      AsyncOperation(listener, string, string)
{

}

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CurrencyConverterActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Waiting...");
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           ...
          return null
         }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void params){
            pDialog.dismiss();
            listener.callback(…);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `AsyncTask` in a separate file (not as an inner class) and reuse it many times. `AsyncTask` doesn't have to be an inner class.

You may need to modify your `AsyncTask` to take additional parameters if needed to make it reusable.

You can also create a constructor for your `AsyncTask` with parameters for the values you need to pass into it and use that constructor to instantiate your `AsyncTask`.

This approach makes sense if the way you use AsyncTasks in different places is the same or at least similar. If you use completely different code in each AsyncTask, you will be better off with separate AsyncTasks (though you may still extract them into separate classes from inner classes).

Comment: But in this way I have problem with the variables that are different for every method that require an AsyncTask... Could you give me more details?

Comment: @AndreaF I updated my answer - create a new constructor and pass all the necessary values this way.

Comment: But how could I get the various results? for example a method returns an ArrayList another method returns a boolean etc.
if I use the async task class as inner i could get rid of this simply using static parameters, with you approach I haven't idea of how could I get the results.

Comment: Well, I don't think you can really get around it if you return different types. Those are really different AsyncTasks in this case and they should have separate classes (inner or not).

Comment: But also with one single type how could I get the result? If there is a way I shoud cast Object every time according the situation.

Comment: The last type in the generic types of AsyncTask is the type returned in doInBackground. You could make it Object and cast it every time but I guess you would have a different code for each situation in doInBackground so it may not be worth it.